# How do I change the resulting code when hitting exclamation mark + Tab in WebStorm?

Tags: html, ide, webstorm, abbreviation

So I wanna edit the template that WebStorm throws me when I enter `!` and then press Tab. This template is using some bad practices which I don't want to delete every single time I create a new html file.

I've already tried looking into Emmet and Live Templates but neither of these seem to affect the way the exclamation mark shorthand generates the code.

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Yes, It's one of the standard Emmet abbreviations (implemented using Live Template functionality). It's possible it's outdated now. 1) What code you do not like? 2) What would you like instead? 3) What Live Template have you tried to modify

Comment: @LazyOne
Specifically this:
<meta content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

for a user friendly html page the user should be allowed to scale it to their likings.
I also would like to auto include a description tag and remove the ie compat tags.

I've not modified the live templates since I didn't find any "template" that creates the html boilerplate there only is `T` and `CD` in the HTML section.

With Emmet I just tried turning it off seeing that the exclamation abbr still works as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Emmet abbreviations are implemented using Live Templates in IDEA based IDEs and are located in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Live templates`.

The HTML ones are grouped under the **Zen HTML** group (the original name of Emmet).

From WebStorm help page (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-zen-coding-support.html):

> With WebStorm, you can use native Emmet templates plus more than 200 additional HTML, CSS, and XSL live templates that are listed under the **Zen CSS**, **Zen HTML**, and **Zen XSL** nodes on the `Editor | Live Templates` page of the IDE settings.

[image]

You may want to also edit `html:5` abbreviation as well since `!` is an alias of that one:

[image]